# Using toggle() with a boolean state flag and a duration

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am using this line where I toggle a div:

```
$(this).closest(".email-settings").find(".notify-email-input").toggle(this.value === "true");
```

Normally you can make the toggle slow by `.toggle('slow')`.
In the code I have I tried this but it does not work.

```
$(this).closest(".email-settings").find(".notify-email-input").toggle(this.value === "true", 'slow');
```

How can I make the toggle slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle) you'll see that the method signature which accepts a boolean, accepts *only* that boolean. It does not take any duration or easing arguments.

Therefore to make this work as you require you'll need to manually check the state of the element and use `hide()` and `show()` separately, something like this:

```js
let $emailInput = $(this).closest(".email-settings").find(".notify-email-input");
let method = this.value === "true" ? 'show' : 'hide';
$emailInput[method]('slow');
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. My original thought was that you could avoid unnecessarily trying to hide/show an already hidden/visible element, but it's not necessary and is an overcomplication

Comment: Works like a charm! Thnx